# Responsive Breakpoints in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive, breakpoints

I know, there are a few existing posts about responsive breakpoints in Bootstrap 4, but unfortunately I can't get them work in my project - even though I studied the other posts thoroughly.

My html: Now, to just get it running, I started with e very simple example:

```
<div class="testClass">Test</div>
```

My personal CSS-file:

```
.testClass {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: blue;
margin-bottom: 3%;
color: white;
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { 
    font-size: 10px;
}
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { 
    font-size: 20px;
}}
```

I used extreme font-sizes to see the difference. As I now try to shrink down my browser-window (I can see that there are bootstrap breakpoints on other bootstrap elements on my page) The font-size in this div stays all the same. Is there anything I have to include to get it work or do I have to do some changes in the bootstrap CSS-file instead of my personal CSS-file?

Comment: @include is SASS, not CSS

Comment: Could you mark where the duplicate question is so those of us who are trying to learn could actually do so? @Themes.guide